# java `byte[] array` vs. `byte array[]`

Tags: java, arrays

While reading the String class in java I noticed a weird constructor declaration

```
public String(byte bytes[], int offset, int length, String charsetName)
```

notice that the array bytes is declared as `byte bytes[]` instead of `byte[] bytes`

is there a difference between the two declarations? the java documentation never mention such possibility..

Comment: I guess `byte bytes[]` is prefered by a lot of C developers, since they are using it there, but you should stick to `byte[] bytes` since this is the more common way to declare arrays in Java.

Comment: study shows that only serial killers do `byte bytes[]`

Comment: @bayou.io another study shows that exaggaration rarely communicates what you really wanted to say

Comment: @Durandal - every study shows that some people have no sense of humor :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference. It just syntactic sugar in array declaration. Matter of taste. You can use any.

Answer (score 0):

No difference. You can declare arrays either way

Comment: Why it is downvoted ? Please correct me if anything wrong i mentioned

Comment: Who knows. Most likely it is because you were shouting. All caps is considered as shouting in netiquette.

Comment: hahaha .. anyway corrected now.

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos   never heard of _netiquette_, lol, thx for that